# How to Make Text Black on .mouseover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been working with jQuery for the past couple of days and have decided to begin implementing it into my own website! A problem seems to have arisen, and I ask for your assistance!

My background is grey, and so is my text (and pretty much everything else), and I like how it looks; but some people may have a hard time seeing it.

**QUESTION:** I want my text paragraphs nested within their own `<div>` tags to turn black on `.mouseover` and have tried a couple of things.

Here is the HTML for the text I want to be black on hover:

```
<div id="text"><p2><b>We are Sorry Users!</b> We are making a larger update that is proving to have quite a few bugs! We are very, very sorry about this! Please bear with us, and thank you for all of your patience!</p></div>
    <hr>
<div id="text"><p2><b>About the New Update</b> This new update will take a while! It is the update for the Arcade tab. Please bear with us as we finish it! We will make many improvements on the pages, and you will (hopefully) find them a lot easier to navigate and much more convinient! Thanks again so much for your continuing support!</p></div>
<div id="text"><p2><b>How to Search</b> To search for games, go to the category of the game, the press CTRL+F! It will open a search bar up, in Chrome, it shows up in the upper right! Type your search, and it will highlight your keywords!</p></div>
<div id="text"><p2><b>Welcome to GameShank!</b> Welcome all fellow Shankers! By now you're probably wondering what this is, right? Well, I guess it's a little bit of everything. But, for now, this website is under construction constantly, and is getting new games daily! Our games are all flash-based, and do not go through third party providers of any sort, only through GameShank! The name is a bit odd, but Shank came from many different things. Shank from the first and second ones, and shanking in Call of Duty! Our website, G Shank, will allow you, our fellow shankers, to shank at your own free will!</p></div>
<div id="text"><p2><b>What is GameShank?</b> Well, GameShank not only provides free and unrestricted games everywhere, but also put all of your favorite social networking and email websites into one. You even get the perks of unlimited free game hosting where you can publish your custom work! No matter where you live! For no charge or credit card at all, you can make your free account to link all of your social networking accounts together in one spot. You can even have your emails forwarded into your inbox for GS! Shank in Call of Duty, play Shank or Shank 2, do anything you want! G Shank has it all. To add to that, G Shank is all free</p></div>
<div id="text"><p2><b>Will it Only be Games?</b> This service will provide you more than games, and that's a promise. Not only will we provide you with <i><b>games</b></i>, but also with <i><b>movie and game news</b></i>, <i><b>videos</b></i>, <i><b>reviews</b></i>, and so much <i><b>more</i></b>! Questions? Email us at <a href="mailto:support@gameshank.com? subject=Contact%20Email">support@gameshank.com</a>!</p></div>
<div id="text"><p2><b>Your Source of Games!</b> Our games are not only available to play to our shankers, but also fully and freely downloadable with no charge! That means, if you like what you're playing, you can just download it! To download, go to our <a href="/arcade">Arcade tab!</a></p></div>
<div id="text"><p2><b>Extra Stuff!</b> Want to see a few more things we plan on? Well <a href="tobeadded.html">see them here</a>! Want to make your browser toolbox invisible until you finish your game? <a href="/howtofullscreen.html" target="_blank">Find out how to here</a>!</div>
```

I want each separate `<div id="text">` to highlight only on highlight of that div.

Here is my jQuery I have tried:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#text").mouseover(function(){
            $(this).css("color","#000000");
        });
    });
</script>
```

If anybody has any ideas, and ideas included with on `.mouseout` script, they would be greatly appreciated; and I don't mean to keep asking for things, but please try to keep the code as jQuery. I don't mind JavaScript, but I'm not very good with it!

Comment: Do not duplicate your ids... Use class names instead.

Comment: `id`s must be unique within a page.  You should not have multiple elements with an `id` of `text`.

Comment: I know that jQuery only takes the first of the id's and edits that one, so then is there any way to make all of the divs text black on hover?

Comment: Most over-complicated alternative to :hover ever.

Comment: @evilscary And yet I see jQuery-powered websites do it all the time...

Comment: Don't make the site so difficult to read to begin with. Make the text high-contrast by default. Users who have a difficult time reading text on your site usually won't go through the trouble of mousing around it; they'll just quit and go somewhere else.

Comment: Also, there is no `p2` tag in html...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IDs MUST be unique. Use a `class` instead.

Additionally, don't use jQuery for this.

CSS:

```css
.text:hover {color:#000}
```

**DEMO**

Here's a jsFiddle to demonstrate...
Using RED in the fiddle to see the effect easier.

http://jsfiddle.net/tSMFt/

Comment: Thanks! This is what I ended up using!

Answer (score 3):

HTML/XML `id` have to be unique throughout the entire document. Since they have to be unique, jquery and the underlying `document.getElementById()` calls will only ever return the **FIRST** matching element.

You should be using a `class` instead:

```
<div class="makemeblack">...</div>
<div class="makemeblack">...</div>

$('.makemeblack').mouseover(....);
```

Comment: This would work great, but I think that the CSS method would be easier. Thanks!